# What is the Start > Run command to goto My Documents folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, run-dialog, my-documents

I believe there is a way to get to My Documents folder from Start > Run  by typing something with a % symbol in it, but forgot how... something like %MyDocuments&

I don't know what these type of shortcuts are called so I cannot google for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type `documents`. Windows will automatically open the **My Documents** folder in Explorer.

[image]

This should work for every folder in your profile directory.

Comment: This will do alright - but I recall the %folder% allowed you to combine with relative path like...  %documents%\AutoHotkey\ to goto AutoHotkey dir?

Comment: @Kairan: If you *think* there is a `%something%` for a certain folder, then that would be an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Just open a command prompt and enter `set` to list all of them. Personally, I don't have one for the My Documents folder. There usually is `%USERPROFILE%` on which you could build though.

Comment: @Kairan There are 2 ways to do it. If you want to use what Windows has provided, you can use %USERPROFILE% (which brings you to C:\Users\Username) and then add the folder as needed so %USERPROFILE%\AutoHotKey for example. Or if it is under Documents folder, then you can have %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Autohotkey. If you use this folder shortcut a lot, you can set a new Environment Variable.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg can you explain why this works? I notice it also works with any folder in `C:\Windows`